# Mouse pointer invisible with dual monitor

Tags: 14.04, mouse, multiple-monitors

I've run into a problem with a new computer with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04. The mouse pointer is invisible when using dual monitors. I've tried disabling the cursor plugin but it doesn't help.

If I disconnect on monitor and boot the computer then the mouse pointer shows up without a problem, and if I then connect the second monitor while the computer is running everything is fine. But if I try and boot the computer with both monitors connected the mouse cursor is invisible, regardless of how many times I reboot the computer.

Also, the cursor was visible during the installation process with both monitors connected.

The computer is a HP EliteDesk 800 Mini G1, with a standard Intel HD Graphics 4600 integrated card, and both monitors are Dell UltraSharp U2515H. I've tried several different mice in all USB ports with no luck.